# How do I get Salt Master to apply a basic SLS file to work against a Salt Minion?

Tags: centos, salt-stack

I am programming and want to push down code with Salt.  I have recently installed Salt minion and Salt master on on two CentOS 7.x servers.  They are both Salt version 2015.8.7.  My `salt '*' test.ping` worked.  This, to me, proves `/etc/salt/minion.yml` and `/etc/salt/master.yml` were set up correctly on their respective servers.  It proves the services are up and running.

Here are the contents of `top.sls`:

```
base:
  '*':
    - core
```

Here are the content of `core.sls`:

```
{{ salt['runtests_helpers.get_sys_temp_dir_for_path']('testfile')  }};
    file:
       - managed
       - source: salt://testfile
```

When I run

```
# salt 'fqdnOfSaltMinionServer' state.apply
```

I get an error like this "..No Top file or external nodes data matches found...Error: Minions returned with non-zero exit code"

How do I uninstall Salt master from the server that I want to be Salt minion?  How do I get a basic .sls file to work?  Ping works. I don't see what is wrong with my `top.sls` or `core.sls` files.  I have a small, simple text file named testfile.  I want to transfer it from the Salt master server to Salt minion.  I don't see what is wrong with my set up.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the yum/rpm provided salt master on centos?   I was facing a similar issue and had to create a /srv/salt directory on the salt master server to hold my files (core.sls and testfile in your example) before I could get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

At least with salt 2016.11.1 (Carbon), this is the default setting (in `/etc/salt/master`) where the top file must reside:

```
#####      File Server settings      #####
##########################################
# Salt runs a lightweight file server written in zeromq to deliver files to
# minions. This file server is built into the master daemon and does not
# require a dedicated port.

# The file server works on environments passed to the master, each  environment
# can have multiple root directories, the subdirectories in the multiple file
# roots cannot match, otherwise the downloaded files will not be able to be
# reliably ensured. A base environment is required to house the top file.
# Example:
# file_roots:
#   base:
#     - /srv/salt/
#   dev:
#     - /srv/salt/dev/services
#     - /srv/salt/dev/states
#   prod:
#     - /srv/salt/prod/services
#     - /srv/salt/prod/states
#
#file_roots:
#  base:
#    - /srv/salt
#
```

As [previous John answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834431/6615134), putting the top file in /srv/salt is what to do if you have not changed the default in /etc/salt/master.